# Failing with the decode of JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

I am trying to decode a JSON response from the youtube API in swift.

The JSON information is:

[image: JSON response from youtube playlist info]

I made a Decodable structure:

```
// Build a model object to import the JSON data.
struct PlaylistInformation: Decodable {
    struct Items: Decodable {
        struct VideoNumber: Decodable {
            struct Snippet: Decodable {
                let title: String
            }
            let snippet: Snippet
        }
        let videoNumber: VideoNumber
    }
    let items: Items
}
```

And I get the error when trying to decode:

```
            // We decode the JSON data get from the url according to the structure we declared above.
        guard let playlistInformation = try? JSONDecoder().decode(PlaylistInformation.self, from: data!) else {
            print("Error: could not decode data into struct") <-- HERE IS THE ERROR
            return
        }

        // Comparing DB Versions.
        let videoTitle = playlistInformation.items.videoNumber.snippet.title as NSString
        print(videoTitle)
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: could not decode data into struct
```

I guess it has something to do with the "items" in the struct, as it is an array... but I have no idea about how to solve that.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the complete error message.

Comment: I included the error message.
And in which format I am supposed to post the JSON?

Comment: You would get more valuable information using a do-try-catch block: `do { let playlistInformation = try ... } catch { print(error) }`

Comment: Posting the JSON response as text would be more helpful than as an image, as it would allow others to try to parse it.

Comment: That's not even remotely close to the actual error. Please [edit] your question and post the completion output of `print(error)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `items` is an array, you have to model it as an array and not a struct:

```
// Build a model object to import the JSON data.
struct PlaylistInformation: Decodable {
    struct Item: Decodable {
        struct Snippet: Decodable {
            let title: String
        }
        let snippet: Snippet
    }
    let items: [Item]
}
```

And then access each item using its index, e.g.

```
let videoTitle = playlistInformation.items[0].snippet.title as NSString
print(videoTitle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the error was coming from the "items" in the struct as it is an array.

The correct Decodable struct is:

```
    struct PlaylistInformation: Decodable {
    struct Items: Decodable {
        struct Snippet: Decodable {
            struct Thumbnails: Decodable {
                struct High: Decodable {
                    let url: String
                }
                let high: High
            }
            struct ResourceId: Decodable {
                let videoId: String
            }
            let publishedAt: String
            let title: String
            let thumbnails: Thumbnails
            let resourceId: ResourceId
        }
        let snippet: Snippet
    }
    let items: [Items]
}
```

Thank you for your help.